# Question about Generating bar graph from COVID19 WHO dataset

Tags: r, graph

I am new to **R**. I was trying to generate a bar graph from WHO COVID19 dataset. I was able to see the graph but it seemed not accurately reflecting the actual data. Please take a look at my code and let me know where it went wrong.

Data: [Full dataset](https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/ecdc/full_data.csv)

[image: new cases in 3 countries]

```
#COVID 19

library(ggplot2)

library(tidyverse)

stats <- read.csv(file.choose())

stats

dim(stats)

colnames(stats) <- c("date","location","new_cases","new_deaths","total_cases","total_deaths")


ThreeCountries <- subset(stats, location =="United States" | location =="China" | location =="Italy")

dim(ThreeCountries)

ggplot(ThreeCountries, aes(x=date, y=new_cases, fill = location)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

The difference is, that `read.csv` does not detect the date as a date, `read_csv` meanwhile does this, thus when plotting, the x-axis is properly scaled as a date.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_csv("https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/ecdc/full_data.csv")
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   date = col_date(format = ""),
#>   location = col_character(),
#>   new_cases = col_double(),
#>   new_deaths = col_double(),
#>   total_cases = col_double(),
#>   total_deaths = col_double()
#> )

df %>% 
  # use dplyr's filter function instead of subset (dplyr is part of the tidyverse)
  filter(location %in% c("United States", "China", "Italy")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = new_cases, fill = location)) +
  # geom_col is better suited than geom_bar, as it does not compute stats on the data
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: If this answers your question, is it possible to upvote and or accept it as the answer?

Comment: Thank you @David!  I have another question: I want to only plot the countries which have new cases > 100 per day. I use  x <- subset.data.frame(df, df$new_cases >= 100), but how to create another subset to pick these countries out?

Comment: After the `filter` command, add `%>% filter(new_cases > 100)`